# selenium: using switchTo().window("WEBVIEW") doesn't work on emulators

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, functional-testing, hybrid-mobile-app

When I am executing hybrid testing on real device, switchTo().window("WEBVIEW") works perfectly, but when I am using emulator, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is no more the preferred way as suggested in appium documentation. You should use context switching.